# Making website fit screen properly on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im having some trouble with some JS code that I found on here to make the content of a page fit properly on any mobile browser. Im using this JS

```
let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
```

and this CSS, I have the -37px as I have a 37px top bar and the css is applied to the section below. I also have overflow:none so that the elastic drag is disabled in safari IOS.

```
.elementor-7 .elementor-element.elementor-element-31d481bb > .elementor-container{
    height: 100vh; /* Fallback for browsers that do not support Custom Properties */
  height: calc((var(--vh, 1vh) * 100) - 37px);
}}
```

I have icons at the bottom of the page that are being cutoff, but I believe this code should just make the section fit the page above the bottom bar on any browser?

Comment: have you found that the javascript is executed after the css?

Comment: Open the Inspector tab in the DevTools, activate the section, and check which CSS rules are applied to the element. We need an [mcve] to tell exactly what is wrong with your code.

Comment: why're you not using height: calc(100vh - 37px); instead of height: 100vh; as you know there always a 37px bar.

Comment: I have amended the fallback to "calc(100vh - 37px);" but it doesnt solve anything in this case as the other code is being used

Comment: The correct CSS is being applied on both desktop and mobile, and the JS is being applied, but the result is not what I need. The content is being hid under the bottom bar on mobile browsers, i need it to always fit the screen above the bar.

This is the CSS being applied on mobile - height: calc((var(--vh, 1vh) * 100) - 37px);